# HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'appname' access to protected services is denied

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm having this error in my application.

backboardd[31] : HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'app name' access to protected services is denied.

I didn't get this issue while running in sumulator.Any idea?

Comment: Hitting the same issue here, I can test it ok on a device though but when I build for ad hoc distribution (Test flight) I get that error.
Have you had any luck in finding what the issue is?

Comment: I'm getting this error only for first time of app launch in the device. Later it runs perfectly. Couldn't figure out any solution. Let me know if you are able resolve the error.

Comment: same error with flex mobile ios project here when I try on device.@pierrephi did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using reachability's startNotifier method, you may have to do so in the mainthread like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.reachability startNotifier];
});
```